# Restriction of Haar Measure Induces a Restriction of Integral Formula

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure

I just need some reality check. Suppose we have a locally compact abelian group $G$ with an **open subgroup** $H$. We equip $G$ with a Haar measure $\mu_G$, while we equip $H$ with the Borel measure $\mu_H$ induced by restricting $\mu_G$ to Borel sets of $H$. It turns out that by open-ness of $H$, we are guaranteed that $\mu_H$ is also a Haar measure. Is it true that for any $f\in L^1(G,\mu_G),$ $$\int_G \chi_{H}(x)f(x)d\mu_G(x) = \int_{H}f_{| H}(x) d\mu_H(x)$$ given that $\chi_H$ is the indicator function on $H$, and $f_{|H}$ is the restriction of $f$ on $H$? I have a feeling that the formula above is true regardless of the fact that $H$ is open. In the case that it is not, it's just that we are not guaranteed that $\mu_H$ has the necessary properties to be a Haar measure (I think outer regularity won't be automatic).

Comment: I wanted to briefly comment on your deleted question. I think that at least the first part of that proof might be saved, depending on the notion of convergence you are using. While I am not sure the last part would work, I still believe that it would be a very interesting question and might be worth undeleting.

Comment: I had more time to think about it now, I might reopen it after editing. I am actually interested in a different convergence indeed.

Comment: I think the standard calculus notion of convergent series is not suitable for your question. One should use the more general notion of convergence: $\sum_{n\in S} a_n$ converges iff for every $\varepsilon>0$ exists a finite set $S_\varepsilon\subset S$ such that for every finite set $S_\varepsilon \subseteq T\subseteq S$ we have $$\left\vert\sum_{n\in T\setminus S_\varepsilon} a_n\right\vert<\varepsilon.$$ With this notion of convergence (which is essentially absolute convergence) all my counterexamples no longer apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is true if $H$ is Borel measurable. As usual, it is enough to check the desired identity on indicator functions (linearity gives simple function which are dense in $L^1$). So let $A\subseteq G$ be a Borel subset. Then we have

\begin{align*}
\int_G \chi_H(x) \chi_A(x) d\mu_G(x)&=d\mu_G(A\cap H) = d\mu_H(A\cap H) \\
&=\int_H \chi_{A\cap H} (x) d\mu_H(x) 
\\
&= \int_H \left.\left(\chi_A\right)\right|_H(x) d\mu_H(x).
\end{align*}

If $H$ is not Borel measurable, then it is already unclear what the first integral in your formula is supposed to mean (because $\chi_H$ would not be Borel measurable).

Comment: $H$ is open, hence Borel

Comment: @JoseAvilez The OP is asking whether the subgroup needs to be open in order for the formula to hold true. Or what did you mean?